# problem with pmatrix closing bracket

Tags: packages, matrices, bordermatrix

I have something like that :

```
    \begin{equation}
    \label{eq:vecdir}
    \mathbf{a}(\mathbf{k}_p) = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1&\\
    e^{j\pi \frac{\mathbf{d}_1}{\lambda}\mathbf{k}_p}&\\
    e^{j\pi \frac{\mathbf{d}_2}{\lambda}\mathbf{k}_p}&\\
    \vdots &\\
    e^{j\pi \frac{\mathbf{d}_{M-1}}{\lambda}\mathbf{k}_p}&\\
    \end{pmatrix}
    \end{equation}
```

But the output is quite weird since the second bracket is opening and not closing.
[image]
It's quite inconvenient could somebody help I don't know what to do since I couldn't reproduce this error.

My packages are :

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage{bm}
 \usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[toc, nonumberlist, acronym, section,automake]{glossaries}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[linktocpage=true,pageanchor=false,french]{tulhypref}
\usepackage[french]{minitoc}
```

Thanks

**EDIT**

This seems to be a problem with `MnSymbol` and `fontspec`. MWE (use xelatex or lualatex):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\let\mathdollar\relax
\begin{document}
 \begin{equation}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    a 
    \end{pmatrix}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since your matrix has only a single column, don't create another one with `&`. Simply use double slashes for the row.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us whether you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. Is the package `tulhypref` available online?  Also, which document class do you use? BTW, what's really puzzling about your example is how `pmatrix`, which is supposed to use large round parentheses, ends up producing large square brackets.

Comment: @Sigur yeah sure thanks but that is not solving it.

Comment: @Mico I'm using XelaTeX. Well the tulhypref can be found here  [link] https://github.com/jcb/these-jcb [/link] and the documentclass is thesul also. Yes and whatsoever xmatrix environment I use It's always the same result

Comment: @apollocreed --- I've narrowed down the list of potential causes, and updated your question with this information.

Comment: @IanThompson thanks a lot that worked, well just removing the MnSymbol package cured everything

Comment: @apollocreed --- OK, I've posted an answer with some extra information that I found.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be caused by a conflict between `MnSymbol` and `fontspec`. From section 3.1 of the [fontspec package manual](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontspec):

> By default, fontspec adjusts LaTeX's default maths setup in order to
>   maintain the correct Computer Modern symbols when the roman font
>   changes. However, it will attempt to avoid doing this if another maths
>   font package is loaded (such as mathpazo or the unicode-math package).
>   If you find that fontspec is incorrectly changing the maths font when
>   it should be leaving well enough alone, apply the [no-math] package
>   option to manually suppress its maths font.

Therefore, a potential solution is as follows (requires xelatex or lualatex):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\let\mathdollar\relax
\begin{document}
 \begin{equation}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    a 
    \end{pmatrix}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Depending on your actual document, another possibility might be to simply remove packages that you don't need. Also (unrelated to the problem), `epsfig` has been deprecated for a long time. You should probably load `graphicx` instead.